# How to prove the following, for $n>4$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be an undirected graph with $n>4$ nodes. Prove that there is a cycle in $G$ or in $G'$?

**Note:** $G'$ is the graph which includes all nodes in $G$ and includes edges iff those edges do not exist in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ does not contain cycles then it is a forest, hence $|E|<|V|$. Hence if $n>3$, the number of edges in $G'$ is $>|V|$, so $G'$ is not a forest and contains a cycle. Here $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ is the set of edges in $G$.

Comment: Could you explain: "Hence if >3, the number of edges in ′ is >||"

Comment: The number of edges in $G'$ is $n(n-1)/2- |E|\gt n(n-1)/2-n+1>n-1=|V|-1$.

Comment: Forest = no cycles. Forest may be disconnected unlike a tree. I am sure you confuse trees and forests.

Comment: No cycles and connected = tree.

Comment: last thing, why (−1)/2−+1>−1

Comment: The difference between LHS and RHS is $n(n-1)/2-2n+2$ which is a quadratic function Draw the graph of that    function.

Comment: This lower bound is wrong: for n=4, G and G' can each be a tree with 3 edges

Comment: $n$ is supposed to be $>4$. See the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The greatest number of vertices an acyclic graph with $n$ nodes can have is $n-1$. On the other hand, $K_n$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}2$ vertices.

Suppose $G$ has $e$ edges and $n$ nodes. If $e>n-1$, then $G$ has a cycle.

Now suppose $e\leq n-1$. Then, $G'$ has $e':=\frac{n(n-1)}2-e$ vertices. We want to show that $G'$ has a cycle, i.e. that $e'>n-1$. Let's substitute the definition of $e'$ from above into this inequality:

$$\frac{n(n-1)}2-e> n-1$$

$e$ is at most $n-1$, so it suffices to show that this holds when $e=n-1$:

$$n(n-1)>4(n-1)$$
$$n>4$$

$n>4$ is a given, and so if $e\leq  n-1$, then $e'>n-1$. Thus, $G'$ has a cycle.

Comment: How acyclic graph is related to my problem, I didn't understand your solution

Comment: @Daniel98 An acyclic graph is a graph that doesn't have a cycle. If $e\leq n-1$, then $G$ is acyclic, i.e. $G$ does not have a cycle.